# use prolog find the logs of a list

Tags: list, logging, prolog

The question is:
Write a predicate log_table(NumberList, ResultList) that binds ResultList to the list of pairs consisting of a number and its log, for each number in NumberList. For example:

```
?- log_table([1,3.7,5], Result).
Result = [[1, 0.0], [3.7, 1.308332819650179], [5, 1.6094379124341003]].
```

Here is my code:

```
log_table([],[]).
log_table([H|T],[[H,Result]|T]):-
    log_table(T,_),
    Result is log(H).
```

the result of my code is :

```
?- log_table([1,3.7,5],R).
R = [[1, 0.0], 3.7, 5].
```

my code can not consider all list members:(
Im a beginner. So,is there someone can help me correct it?

Comment: log_table([H|T],[[H,Result]|R]) :- Result is log(H), log_table(T,R).

Answer (score 1):

Your current predicate:

```
log_table([H|T],[[H,Result]|T]):-
    log_table(T,_),
    Result is log(H).
```

Has a couple of clear issues:

- In the *head* of the second *predicate clause* (`log_table([H|T], [[H,Result]|T]) :- ...`) the tails of the input list (`[H|T]`) and the output list (`[[H,Result]|T]`) are the *same* (they're both `T`). This can't possibly be right since the output is a list of pairs where the first element of a pair is the abscissa to your log function, and the second element is the ordinate. The input list consists of single elements. So the two `T` variables *must be different* (use, for example, `[H|T1]` and `[[H|Result]T2]` instead).
- The line `log_table(T, _)` in your clause intends to recursively generate a list of `X` and `log(X)` pairs from `T`, but then it throws the result away by using `_` (anonymous variable).

@CapelliC shows in his comment the correct way to express the predicate you are trying to write (he uses `T` and `R` for the different list tails).

Another approach would be to use `maplist`:

```
log(X, Y) :- Y is log(X).
log_table(Table, Logs) :- maplist(log, Table, Logs).
```